# Chrome bug? : appended element does not show properly in multi column div

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, append, z-index, multiple-columns

I insert an element into a span which resides inside a p-tag. The span has position relative and the element has position absolute. The inserted div shows properly in FireFox, but not in Google Chrome, see these screenshots:

The result in FireFox:

[image: the result in FireFox]

The result in Google Chrome:

[image: the result in Google Chrome]

And here's the code:

```
<script>

var DV;

function fnInsert() {
    DV.appendTo($('#insertHere'));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    DV = $('#DV').detach();
});

</script>

<style>

#daText {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;

    column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -ms-column-gap: 20px;
    -o-column-gap: 20px;

    column-rule: 0px dotted #ccc;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px dotted #ccc;
    -moz-column-rule: 0px dotted #ccc;
    -ms-column-rule: 0px dotted #ccc;
    -o-column-rule: 0px dotted #ccc;

    column-fill: balance;
    -webkit-column-fill: balance;
    -moz-column-fill: balance;
    -ms-column-fill: balance;
    -o-column-fill: balance;

    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -ms-column-count: 3;
    -o-column-count: 3;
}

#daText p {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0px 0px 22px 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFAA;
}

#daText p:first-of-type {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#daText p span#insertHere {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    color: #FFF;
}

.CK {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div#DV {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #FF7777;
    height: 40px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="daText">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a sem <span id="insertHere">lobortis</span>, tristique lectus id, fermentum tellus. Pellentesque condimentum tincidunt dui, non interdum enim interdum varius. Nullam fringilla erat tellus, non facilisis felis lacinia non. Duis rhoncus arcu lobortis, consequat odio eget, sodales tellus. Nam consectetur tincidunt mauris, ut tempus magna faucibus ut. Morbi ultricies felis quis erat ultrices, id aliquet enim faucibus. Morbi tincidunt, sem a interdum euismod, lacus lorem cursus massa, eu sodales nisi metus vel dolor.<p>
</div>

<p>
    <span onclick='fnInsert()' class='CK'>insert div</span>
</p>

<div id="DV"></div>

</body>
```

In Chrome, the inserted div seems to go under the next column.

Of course I tried to set a z-index, but it doesn't help ..

I created a JSfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/foleox/GppVK/ - it uses jQuery (just for convenience).

Does anyone know a solution to make it work in Chrome? What's the cause?

Do other browsers suffer from it also?